# How to efficiently fuzzy find and sort a big list in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, fuzzy-search

I'm currently working on a project where one of the requirements was to "group similar items". Now, what I have to do is pull items from a CSV, sort those, and dump the data into an Excel sheet, easy enough. My issue is with the sorting part of this, as our naming convention for items is a bit all over the place, meaning I can't just do a simple alphabetical sort. As of now, I have proof of concept code that will take all of our items, parse them into a class I made to hold them represented as the following

```py
class item:
    def __init__(self, name, line):
        self.name = name
        self.inserted = 0
        self.line = line
```

Where `name` represents the item's name (used in comparison later), whether it has been inserted in my new list, and the line number in the original file (might be used later to actually pull the data, though I may just add the necessary data to the class itself). Once I have a list containing all of our items, as of now I simply iterate through all of the items and use the FuzzyWuzzy `token_sort_ratio` function to find any two items that have > 70 Levenshtein distance from each other. This is where my issue lies, as the only way I have found to do this so far is for every item, go through the list *again* to look for matches. The only optimizations I have put in so far is that `inserted` tag, so if the item has already been put somewhere in my list, it won't consider it again. Here's the function that does this:

```py
def sort_items():
    # Agh. Suuuuper inefficient
    sorted_list = []
    counter = 0
    for item in items:
        progress = "{:.2f}".format((counter / len(items)) * 100)
        print(f"Current Progress: {progress}%", end='\r')
        if item.inserted != 1:
            # Need to add this and similar items to the sorted list
            sorted_list.append(item)
            item.inserted = 1
            counter += 1
            for item1 in items:
                # This is about o(N^2). Yikes.
                if item1.inserted != 1:
                    # Not in the list, is it similar?
                    if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(item.name, item1.name) >= 70:
                        sorted_list.append(item1)
                        item1.inserted = 1
                        counter += 1
```

This is an issue since the length of the `items` list is about 26,500 items. Again, this is proof of concept code that I wrote in an afternoon, so it's a bit ugly. It *works*, it just takes ~20 minutes to do so. Some solutions I have considered was possibly breaking the list into smaller segments and passing them into multiple processes, then joining the lists together at the end which may increase the speed somewhat, though I haven't had the time to actually explore this option yet. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you are doing this for some specific reason, I would use someone else's library

e.g.
https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz

Comment: @TomMcLean That library seems to do the same as the one I am using: FuzzyWuzzy with python-Levenshtein. The problem itself isn't doing the Levenshtein calculation, it's the efficiency of going through a list twice looking for the matches. I should clarify, I'm not trying to make a fuzzy finder, I'm simply trying to group a list of items by similar names.

Comment: Have you considered some [clustering algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)? In some of them you can provide your own distance function as 'metric' or something like that

Comment: [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) is a significantly faster implementation of the fuzzywuzzy library. You might be able to use [rapidfuzz.process.cdist](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/process.html#rapidfuzz.process.cdist), which calculates the similarity between all elements and supports multiprocessing

Comment: Interesting, interesting. I'm going to look into RapidFuzz and give it a shot as it seems very promising. Thanks for this, I'll update here with results when I have time to implement it.

Comment: Wow, even without working on implementing multiprocessing I'm seeing a time reduction from 20 minutes to just over 4 minutes. I suspect when I parallelize this program, it's going to be really fast. Awesome work on this! (I noticed you were the author)